# DC/DC split rail converter like TI's Fly-Buck™ coupled inductor topology but with a non-inverting buck converter

Tags: circuit-design, voltage-regulator, ltspice, buck, texas-instruments

## Introduction

First of all, I hope you can read this through. It's rather long!

I was trying to design a DC/DC converter for a Class-D amplifier that requires a 48V input and also an auxiliary 12V input for the FET drivers and other circuitry. Additionally, the input stage previous to the amplifier requires some op-amps that need to be powered with either a typical ±12V symmetric/split-rail power supply or it can be powered with a single rail +12V with DC-biased references.

If I decide to go with a single-rail supply, I will need additional circuitry for biasing various op-amps and such. For this additional cost, I wanted to investigate the viability of a split-rail Fly-Buck™ topology, which is a traditional inverting buck converter with a coupled inductor (1:1) that generates a virtual ground and a non-inverting rail.

### Background

I have gathered a couple of resources here if you are interested in reading them:

- [SLVA369A: Creating a Split-Rail Power Supply With a Wide Input Voltage Buck Regulator](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva369a/slva369a.pdf)... here, TI didn't even market the Fly-Buck trademark (2009).
- [SNVA833: EMI and Thermal Design Tips and Tricks for 48-V IGBT/SiC/GaN Supply for Automotive Motor Drive Inverters](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva833/snva833.pdf)
- [Fly-Buck: Frequently Asked Questions (FAQs)](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/posts/fly-buck-frequently-asked-questions-faqs)

From what I've seen, the Fly-buck topology only works when you have a current mode controller, so there are more converter topologies than TI advertises that should in fact work, if and only if we guarantee they work in Forced PWM, thus loosing efficiency when the load is very small. The [LMR38020](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr38020.pdf) is one such example where FPWM is a must.

### Problem

I am not familiar with TINA-TI and I do not have access to PSPICE, so I decided to use LTSpice to simulate my circuits. For this reason, I was rather limited with my choices since most new models are encrypted. After a thorough research, I decided to use the [LM5164](https://www.ti.com/product/LM5164), a *6V to 100V tolerant, 1A output, synchronous buck converter with Fly-Buck compatibility*. The reason behind my choice is because I found it very cheap from my supplier, but here's the problem. The unencrypted Spice model DOES NOT WORK in Fly-Buck operation! Why you ask? Read it yourself (from file "LM5164-Q1_TRANS.LIB", line 51):

```
 *      b. Ground pins have been tied to 0V internally,therefore this model cannot be used for inverting topologies.
```

My problem arises from the fact that TI's solution requires the buck converter to be put in **inverting mode**, but that is troublesome with this simulation model.

### Possible Solution

I'm still learning EE, but I've come up with the following solution which I'm quite surprised that **it works** in the first place. What I did is to put the buck converter in non-inverting mode and generating a negative rail below it, using the default circuit ground as the 0V reference. TI in SLVA369A instead put the buck converter in inverting mode and used the coupled inductor to generate a symmetrical rail above the virtual ground, thus getting +12V.

In my solution, I made a symmetric 15V supply since I'll be using further filtering down the line using LDOs and such to filter out noise. I've also used a class Y capacitor for EMI reasons, like in SNVA833. I suppose it might not be necessary though. I also needed to use a piecewise voltage source since the model did not like the sudden increase in voltage.

[image: LM5164 in non-inverting fly-buck topology]
[image: Transient simulation]

### Questions

1. What are the inconveniences of generating a rail below ground instead of generating a virtual ground?
2. Do you see any flaws in my design? How can I improve it?
3. Why is there a +0.6V difference in the negative rail when the simulation starts? Am I correct to assume it's because of the diode? What impact can it have in my circuits?

Comment: If you use a buck converter without sync FET and with a diode in that place, there will not be a 0.6 V diode drop difference in the output voltages. Watch the regulator response during light load currents on the positiv output rail.

Comment: The negative rail wont be regulated. The voltage at startup is likely due to LTspice "thinking too much" when calculating the initial operation point. You can append "uic" or "startup" to the tran command

Comment: @tobalt The negative rail will only experience about 1/5th the power consumption of the primary side, and the `uic` did indeed fix the problem, while also changing the constant current loads with resistors.

Comment: @Jens, I have tried the LM5010A asynchronous buck regulator but the negative rail is completely out of sync with  the positive rail. I'll keep with the LM5164 but I'll have to investigate the behavior in DCM mode, since the model does indeed simulate it. Thanks for the tip. I suppose since I'll be using LDO for post-regulation, if I adjust the circuit correctly, there will not be any problems.

Comment: Its irrelevant what the secondary rail has to supply... Change the load on the positive regulated rail and even leave the load on the secondary rail constant..Then look at the voltage change on the second rail